# ActiveAdmin causing error after upgrading Rails to 4-1-1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I just upgraded to Rails 4-1-1 and I'm having some problems with active admin. I'm getting this error:

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (5 for 4):
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/form_builder.rb:85:in `initialize'
```

Here's the complete error code:

```
Started GET "/admin/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-03 18:14:36 +0200
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/active_admin-ee996b09edb9/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/active_admin_logged_out (5.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (5 for 4):
  formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/form_builder.rb:85:in `initialize'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/active_admin-ee996b09edb9/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:15:in `initialize'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1146:in `instantiate_builder'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:433:in `form_for'
  formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:167:in `block in semantic_form_for'
  formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:190:in `with_custom_field_error_proc'
  formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:166:in `semantic_form_for'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/active_admin-ee996b09edb9/lib/active_admin/view_helpers/form_helper.rb:9:in `active_admin_form_for'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/active_admin-ee996b09edb9/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb:5:in `___sers_aljazfajmut__bundler_ruby_______active_admin_ee___b__edb__app_views_active_admin_devise_sessions_new_html_erb__1960339914767360192_70243798002100'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:238:in `default_render'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:165:in `to_html'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:158:in `respond'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:151:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:400:in `respond_with'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/devise-602778793022/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `new'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionview/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.7.159) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:43:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.7.159) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:43:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.7.159) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:22:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.7.159) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:16:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.7.159) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:28:in `call'
  mixpanel (4.0.8) lib/mixpanel/middleware.rb:29:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb:515:in `call'
  /Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/railties/lib/rails/application.rb:142:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Any idea why is that happening?

Before that it worked perfectly fine..

Thanks

Comment: Please share some relevant code in relation to this error.

Comment: Hey, I shared the complete error code.. Hope that will help, let me know if I should post anything else

Comment: Lets discuss this on chat join me at: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with `Gem dependencies`. Add these lines to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'activeadmin', :git => 'git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git'
gem 'formtastic' , :git => 'git://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic.git'
```

Also, as per the chat session, there was issue with `rake` version:

`gem install rake`

Comment: I am running into same issue. I have checked your solution, but not worked for me. Got `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "formtastic":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      formtastic (~> 2.3) ruby

    formtastic (3.1.0.pre)`

Comment: @Shamithc Looks like current version in git repo of `formtastic` is `3.1.0.pre` BUT for `activeadmin` you require gem version of `formtastic` to be `~> 2.3`. Just source it from RubyGems as `gem 'formtastic', '~> 2.3'`